# Optional string not matched in Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex

The string `s` is bigger, but I have shortened it to simplify.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Blah. Tel.: 555 44 33 22."
>>> m = re.search(r"\s*Tel\.:\s*(?P<telephone>.+?)\.", s)
>>> m.group("telephone")
'555 44 33 22'
```

The code above works, but if I wrap the regex in `()?` to make it optional, I don't get any telephone.

```
>>> m = re.search(r"(\s*Tel\.:\s*(?P<telephone>.+?)\.)?", s)
>>> m
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x9369890>
>>> m.group("telephone")
```

What's the problem here? Thanks!

**Edit:**

This is part of a larger regular expression in which I'm getting many values from every line of a big file.

```
regex = r"^(?P<title>.[^(]+);" \
         "\s*(?P<subtitle>.+)\." \
         "\s*Tel\.:\s*(?P<telephone>.+?)(\.|;)" \
         "\s*(?P<url>(www\.|http://).+?\.[a-zA-Z]+)(\.|;)" \
         "(\s*(?P<text>.+?)\.)?" \
         "\s*coor:(\s*(?P<lat>.+?),\s*(?P<long>.+?))?$"
```

One sample line could be:

```
l = "Title title; Subtitle, subtitle. Tel.: 555 33 44 11. www.url.com. coor: 11.11111, -2.222222
```

And other sample line:

```
l = "Title2 title; Subtitle2, subtitle. Tel.: 555 33 44 11. www.url2.com. coor: 44.444444, -6.66666
```

It's a really big regex, so that's why I didn't post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is too unspecific in what the `title` and `subtitle` bits are matching. They are gobbling up the telephone part, and if that is made optional, it continues at the next part of the regex (and succeeds). Only if it's not optional, the regex engine has to backtrack so it can find an overall match.

Try

```
regex = r"^(?P<title>[^;]+);" \
         "\s*(?P<subtitle>[^.]+)\." \
         "(\s*Tel\.:\s*(?P<telephone>.+?)(\.|;))?" \
         "\s*(?P<url>(www\.|http://).+?\.[a-zA-Z]+)(\.|;)" \
         "(\s*(?P<text>.+?)\.)?" \
         "\s*coor:(\s*(?P<lat>.+?),\s*(?P<long>.+?))?$"
```

Answer (score 2):

`(anything)?` matches the zero string at the very beginning of your string (before `Blah`), so it is happy and does not bother searching further.

EDIT:

If you have many lines and only some of them contain the wanted string, try the following:

```
import re

rex = re.compile(r"\s*Tel\.:\s*(?P<telephone>.+?)\.")
for line in lines:
    m = rex.search(line)
    if m:
        print m.group("telephone")
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because an empty string is a valid match for your regular expression, and is preferred over the longer match.

You might want to take a look at [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall).

**edit**: You can move the optionality out of your regular expression altogether:

```
import re
s = "Blah. Tel.: 555 44 33 22."
m = re.search(r"\s*Tel\.:\s*(?P<telephone>.+?)\.", s)
if m is not None:
  print m.group("telephone")
```

Comment: Thanks, and how can I avoid this 'lazy' behaviour?

Comment: Try `re.findall`. This will give you all matches (empty or not.)

Comment: @Menda - why do you want to do this? You will get a lot of empty matches.

Comment: @Menda I agree with @eumiro that if you explained what you're trying to do, we may be able to give better advice.

Comment: @eumiro Hmmm.. I don't understand quite well what are you asking me. I have a big file with many lines. Some lines have telephone numbers in it, some haven't. I wan't to get the telephone numbers from the lines which have them.

Comment: If that's all you want to do, then you can simply use your first regex (without the parentheses), call `m=re.search(...)` and then check whether `m is None`. If it is, then there's no match. Otherwise you can proceed looking at `m.group(...)`.

Comment: @Menda: aix is right, just search and then test, whether it found anything. Your `()?` around the whole expression does not make sense. Compare his and my solution and apply to your needs.

Comment: I have edited my question just in case you know other solution.